# Query reverse dns lookups with dnspython

Tags: python, dns, dnspython

I am trying to query reverse lookups in dnspython. Unfortunately, the from_address() function does not let me hand over a IP by variable. Any ideas why?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import dns.resolver,dns.reversename

with open("test", "r") as ips:
    for ip in ips:
        ip = str(ip)
        n = dns.reversename.from_address(ip)
        print str(dns.resolver.query(n,"PTR")[0])
```

I am new to python; would be great if somebody could help out!

Comment: Your code works for me with hardcoded list of IPs. Are you sure the file's content is what you think it is?

Comment: IP addresses are contained within the file overhanded. When I type one manually it works fine. However, something must be wrong with the file. Does it Need a Special Encoding? Is it recognized as text?

Answer (score 3):

I really doubt you are still working on this but if you print out each IP you will realize there is a newline \n in every ip which dns.reversename.from_address() does not like:

```
192.168.1.1

192.168.1.2

192.168.1.3
```

This causes an exception:

```
dns.exception.SyntaxError: Text input is malformed.
```

You can easily change the line:

```
ip = str(ip)
```

to:

```
ip = str(ip).strip()
```

and it will strip out all of the whitespace (which there should be none in a list of well formed IP addresses leaving you with this:

```
192.168.1.1
192.168.1.2
192.168.1.3
```

If you were experiencing the same text formatting exception, and your IP addresses are well formed, this should solve your problem.  Sorry I'm 2 years late, I stumbled upon this Googling the dns.reversename.from_address().  If your list of IPs is not well formatted, you could use something like [ippy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ippy) to filter out your bad ones.